# DatabaseCleaner strategy transaction is not working

Tags: cucumber, capybara, database-cleaner

In My env.rb

```
Before do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end
```

Also created a hook in my shared_steps.rb

```
Before('@database_cleaner_before') do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

After('@database_cleaner_after') do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

In My feature file

```
@database_cleaner_after @database_cleaner_before
Scenario: I can sign up with a new valid "Email" and "Username"
      When I enter a new valid "Email"
      And I enter a new "Username"
      And I enter a "Password"
      And I click on the "Sign up" button
      Then I should see a message with word "Signed Up" and "Successfully"
```

I am using gem:

```
Capybara 2.0.2
cucumber 1.2.1
database_cleaner 0.9.1
selenium-webdriver 2.30.0
cucumber-rails 1.3.0
Rails 3.1.0
```

In my database.rb

```
require 'active_record'
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :trancation is working fine (delete all record from database) but DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction is not rolling back my database record why?. Am I missing somethings?

Comment: Hi @RKP, have you solved this problem? I encounter exactly the same problem

Comment: Could you try upgrading to the latest version of `database_cleaner`?